# Login button & div(account) hide and show

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Hi i have a problem with my login button. I want to make if user login; account will show , login button will hide. Else login button show , account hide.

I'm using jquery to code it but not sure is correct or not. Besides I feel like it is not working at all. If can please give me some suggestion which place need to be correct. Thank you.

These are the codes below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <script src='https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js'></script>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <title>Document</title>

    <style>

       .login{

           float:right;

           margin-right:50px;

           margin-top:10px;

           text-decoration:none;

           background-color:darkcyan;

           color:white;

           padding:10px 25px;

           border-radius:6px;
       } 

       .login:hover{

           background-color:white;

           border: 2px solid darkcyan;

           color:darkcyan;

          overflow:hidden;

       }

       .account{

           margin-left:70%;

           margin-top:15px;

           display:inline-block;

           position:relative;

       }

       /* Popup container */

       .notification{

           position:absolute;

           display: inline-block;

          cursor: pointer;

       }

      /* The actual popup (appears on top) */

      .notification .popuptext {

       visibility: hidden;

        width: 15px;

       background-color: #555;

       color: #fff;

       text-align: center;

       border-radius: 60px;

       padding: 2px 4px;

       position: absolute;

       z-index: 1;

       bottom: 96%;

       left: 20%;

       margin-left: 10px;

       }


    /* Toggle this class when clicking on the popup container (hide and show the popup) */

    .notification .show {

     visibility: visible;

     -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s;

     animation: fadeIn 1s

     }


    @-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {

    from {opacity: 0;}

    to {opacity: 1;}

    }

   @keyframes fadeIn {

    from {opacity: 0;}

    to {opacity:1 ;}

    }
       .cart{

           margin-left:50px;

           position:absolute;

           }

           
       .user{

        margin-left:108px;

        position:absolute;

       }

       /* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */

       .user {

        position: relative;

       display: inline-block;

       }

       /* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */

       .user-dropdown {

       display: none;

       position: absolute;

      background-color: #fff;

      min-width: 100px;

       box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);

       z-index: 1;

       }

      /* Links inside the dropdown */

       .user-dropdown a {

        color: black;

       padding: 12px 10px;

       text-decoration: none;

       display: block;

       text-align: center;

        }

      /* Change color of dropdown links on hover */

      .user-dropdown a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}


      /* Show the dropdown menu on hover */

      .user:hover .user-dropdown {display: block;}


    </style>

</head>

<body>

    <a href="" class="login" >Login</a>

    <div class="account">

        <div class="notification"  onclick="myFunction()">

            <i class='fas fa-bell' style='font-size:36px'></i>

                <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup">1</span>
        </div>

        <div class="cart">

            <i class='fas fa-shopping-cart' style='font-size:36px'></i>

        </div>

        <div class="user">

            <i class='fas fa-user-circle' style='font-size:36px'></i>

            <i class='fas fa-angle-down' style='font-size:24px'></i>

            <div class="user-dropdown">

                <a href="#">Link 1</a>

                <a href="#">Link 2</a>

                <a href="#">Link 3</a>

              </div>

        </div>

    </div>



    <script>

        // When the user clicks on <div>, open the popup

        function myFunction() {

          var popup = document.getElementById("myPopup");

          popup.classList.toggle("show");

        }

        </script>

    <script>

  // if user login, account show; login button hide.

  // else login button show; account hide.

  $(document).ready(function(){

  $(".login").click(function(){

    $(".account").toggle();

  });

});

</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change `<a href="" class="login" >Login</a>` to something like `<button class="login" >Login</button>` and it should work

**EDIT**

You will need to use something like `sessionStorage` or `localStorage` or `cookie` to save a user session (to see if the user is logged in). I have used `sessionStorage`. Best is to use `sessionStorage` in your case.

Sessions are used to save user data for a particular session, like user details after logging in. This data is deleted after the browser is closed. Hence somewhat secure as well.

Here you can find how to look for sessionStorage in a browser: [http://css-workshop.com/check-cookies-local-and-session-storage-in-ie11-chrome-opera-and-firefox/#:~:text=Check%20local%20and%20session%20storage%20in%20Chrome%20and%20Opera,Session%20Storage%E2%80%9D%20and%20explore%20it](http://css-workshop.com/check-cookies-local-and-session-storage-in-ie11-chrome-opera-and-firefox/#:%7E:text=Check%20local%20and%20session%20storage%20in%20Chrome%20and%20Opera,Session%20Storage%E2%80%9D%20and%20explore%20it).

Here is the full javascript code for login. Rest of the code should be same. Just replace the code in `$(document).ready(function(){})` section

```
  // if user login, account show; login button hide.
  // else login button show; account hide.
   $(document).ready(function(){


    //By default account div will be hidden
    // And login will be shown
    $(".account").hide();

    // if login clicked
    // and login successful
    // store a session
    $(".login").click(function(){

        // Store a session key
        // in this case, i have saved a random number
        // you can store something unique
        sessionStorage.setItem("session_key", Math.random());

        // Then hide the login button
        // And show account
        $(".login").hide();
        $(".account").show();

    });

    // Now check if session already exists
    // If session exists, show account div
    // and hide login div
    if (sessionStorage.getItem('session_key') !== null){
        $(".login").hide();
        $(".account").show();
    }
```

Comment: thank you. But how to let login button hide it, if user login?

Comment: @CharlotteChee, check now.